# Why i cant assign and use the value inside a component?

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I have a service to share the variables among the components as follows,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class AppMessageQueuService {    
    checkOutPageParams: Subject<Object>;
    constructor() {     
        this.checkOutPageParams = new Subject<string>();

    }

}
```

I use this service to pass the following parameters to another component,

```
  this.appMsgService.checkOutPageParams.next({
            'userId': listItem.userInfo.userId,
            'listingId': listItem.listingId,
            'event': this.event
        });
```

I can see the values being assigned to event when i debug, this is how i get the values in the 2nd component,

```
 this.appMsgService.checkOutPageParams.asObservable()
            .switchMap((params: Object) => {
                let userId = params['userId'];
                let listingId = params['listingId'];
                this.event = params['event'];
                return this.checkOutInforService.getCheckoutDetails(userId, listingId);
            }).subscribe((checkoutDetail: CheckoutUserDetail) => {
                this.checkoutInfoDetails = checkoutDetail;
            });
            console.log(this.event) //this returns undefined
```

I can see the value being assigned to event as well. but when i print a console.log(this.event) after the above lines, it says undefiend.

What is the issue. how can i assign the value to the event and use it within the component 2.

Comment: No you can't. Observables are asynchronous, so console.log executes before this.event is assigned.  Move the statement inside your `subscribe` block.

Comment: how to use that value then

Comment: use the value inside your subscribe block.

Comment: @pixelbits it says params undefined

Comment: where are you trying to use `params` when the error occurs (post code)?

Comment: please post an answer

Comment: @pixelbits i cant access params and assign  this.event = params['event']; inside the subscribe method

Comment: You've already assigned it in your `switchMap` - just use it.

Comment: when i try to use it says undefined, thats the problem.

Comment: any idea on the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but you could try:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin'


this.appMsgService.checkOutPageParams.asObservable()
            .switchMap((params: Object) => {
                return Observable.forkJoin ([
                  this.checkOutInforService.getCheckoutDetails(userId, listingId),
                  Observable.of(params)])
            }).subscribe((result) => {
                this.checkoutInfoDetails = result[0] as CheckoutUserDetail;
                this.params = result[1];
                ... do with params as you wish ...
            });
```

Comment: Observable.forkJoin is not a function

Comment: You have to import the operator

Comment: it works, but when i bind in the ui i cannot see the data, any idea?     <p><i class="  zmdi zmdi-calendar icon icon--white-icon "></i>{{event}}</p>

Comment: cant i directly bind these variables to the ui elements?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42547992/why-the-data-binded-does-not-show-here